# How I can make the subcategory features thumbnail clickable in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using this function to display wooCommerce subcategories and products in separate lists
My problem is that it only makes the subcategory name a clickable link, and I want also the thumbnail image to be clickable and link to the actual category.
How can I achieve that?
Thanks.

```
function tutsplus_product_subcategories( $args = array() ) {
    $parentid = get_queried_object_id();

$args = array(
    'parent' => $parentid
);

$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

if ( $terms ) {
    echo '<ul class="product-cats">';

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li class="category">';                 
            woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail( $term );
            echo '<h2>';
                echo '<a href="' .  esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">';
                    echo $term->name;
                echo '</a>';
            echo '</h2>';
        echo '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. To make the category image clickable, just place `woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail` in a href, like so:

```
    function tutsplus_product_subcategories( $args = array() ) {
    $parentid = get_queried_object_id();

$args = array(
    'parent' => $parentid
);

$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

if ( $terms ) {
    echo '<ul class="product-cats">';

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li class="category">';                 
            $catlink = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">';
                echo $catlink;
                woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail( $term );
                echo '</a>';
                            echo '<h2>';
                                echo $catlink;                 
                    echo $term->name;
                echo '</a>';
            echo '</h2>';
        echo '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}

}
```

I created variable `$catlink` so that the url doesn't have to be pulled twice.